# How do I pip install Linux packages on a Windows machine (for AWS Lambda)?

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, pip

I'm trying to write a Python AWS Lambda script. The Python code works locally in Windows, but it's using the **Windows packages** installed through pip. When uploading to AWS Lambda, I need to include the **Linux packages**.

For example, when I run `pip install pandas` I get:

```
Downloading pandas-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

But what I need (for uploading to AWS Lambda) is:

```
pandas-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

**My Attempt**

I have tried to use Docker to simulate a Linux environment in Windows. My idea is to pip install the Linux packages in Docker and then copy them to my local machine. I think this can be done through a **Docker Volume**. I have tried to do this using the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Download python packages to /usr/src/app/lib
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/lib
RUN pip3 install pandas -t /usr/src/app/lib

# Copy the python pacakges to local machine
VOLUME host:/myvol
RUN mkdir /myvol
COPY /usr/src/app/lib /myvol
```

But when I run docker build I get the error:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder233015161/usr/src/app/lib: no such file or directory

Comment: Does `/usr/src/app/lib` exist locally?

Comment: I don't think `COPY` will run with full paths (assuming you're running `docker build . -t some_image`), since it will just look in the current build context. So even if `/usr/src/app/lib` *did* exist in your windows environment, it won't find it

Comment: /usr/src/app/lib is a path inside the Docker container. The `pip3 install` command works fine. I'm trying attempting to copy out the folder inside the Docker container (/usr/src/app/lib) to the Windows folder ('host'). The 'host' directory does exist.

Comment: @maurera no, `COPY <host_path> <container_path>` is how the command works. You are looking for `/usr/src/app/lib` on your host machine the way it's currently written

Comment: You are probably looking for `RUN mv /usr/src/app/lib /host/`. I'll check to see if that will actually work, because I'm doubtful tbh

Comment: @C.Nivs - I've just tried this. There is no error, but I don't see anything in the windows 'host' folder

Comment: That's because it's not actually copying anything to your local machine, it's mounting to the image instead. When you are trying to upload packages to AWS Lambda, can it take a docker image? You may be able to build the image in AWS. Otherwise, if Lambda can take wheel files, you could just download the linux wheels and ship those

Comment: AWS Lambda requires a zipped file of the script and dependencies. I have 2 workarounds I'm using now (1 - ftp upload out from Docker and 2 - run 'pip install' from a Linux AWS EC2 instance), but both of these seem quite round about methods. I could possibly use the linux wheels directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209324/discussion-between-c-nivs-and-maurera).

Comment: @C.Nivs - I've summarized your explanation from the chat into an answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [explanation from @C.Nivs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209324/discussion-between-c-nivs-and-maurera), this can be done using Docker interactively:

1. First run docker interactively with `docker run -it python:3.6-slim bash`. Then create a folder 'target' and pip install into it (this installs the linux packages). Make note of the container id (my command line shows root@31d9be68deec:/#. The container id is `31d9be68deec`)

```
mkdir /target 
pip install pandas -t /target
```

2. Then open a new command prompt and use docker cp to copy files from container to local. The following copies from the `target` folder in the container to the local folder libs.

```
docker cp <container_id>:/target libs
```

That's it. The python packages are now available in the local folder `libs`.

Note from @C.Nivs: "COPY doesn't do what it's name might suggest. COPY is a build step that copies files from the build context (where the image is being built) to the image itself. It doesn't allow things to go the other way".