# How to pip install Linux wheels from a Windows machine?

Tags: python, powershell, azure-devops, pip, python-wheel

I'm using an Azure DevOps Pipeline to build a Python project (Azure Function). I want to stick with a Windows build agent and use PowerShell to `pip install` packages. Doing so results in many Python wheels that are appended with `win_amd64.whl` or `platform_system == "Windows"`.

The target host is Linux so I need the Python wheels to be `manylinux_x86_64.whl` / `platform_system != "Windows"`.

**Is there a flag I can pass `pip install` to specify which OS to download packages/wheels for?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604477/how-do-i-pip-install-linux-packages-on-a-windows-machine-for-aws-lambda
This seems like the exact copy of your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+download+windows+linux

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found a [proposal](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5453) from back in 2018.

Given this proposal hasn't been ratified yet and none of us can wait till it does.

Out of curiosity can you use something like **Docker hub** with WSL2 **(Windows Sub System for Linux)** as an alternative? To still be able to develop on Windows and still be able to easily download Linux pip wheels like `manylinux_x86_64.whl` in order to target a Linux host?

Some more research on using Docker to create [Windows or Linux images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Since I'm using build tasks in Azure DevOps, I think the easy options are to either set the build agent as Linux or install Azure Function Core Tools and use its built in "magic" to handle things (oryx).